# Is there an elegant way to find an item in a list of list with multiple layers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

List comprehensions are often cited as an elegant way to iterate through list of lists, like  `[item for sublist in original_list for item in sublist]`.

However to me it seem to only deal with simple list of lists that has 2 layers: `[[1,2],[3,4]`.

Is there an universal elegant way to find an item in unknown number of layers of list of lists?
`[0,[1,[2,[3]]],[4,[5]],6]`.

I have thought about flattening all the elements into a single list before checking, but any simpler methods?

Comment: Use a set or mapping. If you're iterating to do lookup, your data structure is not well suited to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to flatten the array, you can use recursion to iterate over a list and recurs on each another list inside it.

Code:

```
def check(lst, x):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if type(lst[i]) == list: # If there is another list inside it
            if check(lst[i], x): # If the value x exist in lst[i]
                return True
        elif lst[i] == x: # If there is no more list inside it
            return True
    return False # X can't be found in lst.


print(check([0, [1, [2, [3]]], [4, [5]], 6], 5)) # Output: True
print(check([0, [1, [2, [3]]], [4, [5]], 6], 9)) # Output: False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an element exists in the list, you must flatten it first, as below, then search for it in the flattened list

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten

lis = [0,[1,[2,[3]]],[4,[5]],6]

new_lis = list(flatten(lis))

print(new_lis)
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(6 in new_lis)
// True
```